# Arduino pro mini A6/A7 as output

Tags: arduino

i,m trying to use pins A6 and A7 as digital output pins . but there is 1.5v (instead of 3V) on this pins as output high.

```
    fp[0] = A1;
    fp[1] = A2;
    fp[2] = A3;
    fp[3] = A6;
    fp[4] = A7;
    fp[5] = 6;
    fp[6] = 7;
    fp[7] = 8;
    fp[8] = 9;
    fp[9] = 10;

    for (int i = 0; i < fp_size; i++) {

      pinMode(fp[i], OUTPUT);
      digitalWrite(fp[i], HIGH);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the datasheet for AT328p, it indicates that A6 & A7 are analog exclusive pins. You can't use them as general purpose digital pins.